# pagespeed Ставит плашку при проверке страницы

Tags: html, pagespeed-insights

При проверке страницы появляется фиксированая плашка с требованием обновить браузер и портит CLS, кто-нибудь знает как её убрать?
[image: Плашка]

Comment: Начать стоит с другого вопроса — как она появилась? По умолчанию нигде никаких плашек не бывает, значит кто-то где-то осознанно добавил её на сайт — вот ищите, кто и где

Comment: На сайте её нет. Её видно только при обходе с помощью pagespeed.

Comment: Логичный вопрос - а вы пробовали заходить через старый браузер-то? Если вы заходите через новый браузер - совершенно логично, что её не будет

Comment: Я вот сейчас прогнал pagespeed на своём сайте и заметил, что он присылает запросы с юзер-агентом Chrome 94 — вот видимо примерно в этой версии браузера и нужно проверять